# query_posts not reading correct categories

Tags: categories, query-posts

I'm using this code (below) to display posts from a category on two separate pages. The first page lists category 32 and the other lists category 31. However, on the second page it displays posts from both categories and the first page doesn't display all the posts from its category. The first page has 13 but there are only 10. The second page displays 14 but there are 19. I have no code to tell the page to only display a certain number of posts. Any idea why this is happening?

```
<?php
query_posts('cat=32');
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
the_content();
endwhile;
?>
```

I was previously using list_category_posts plug-in but I thought this was an easier solution.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, avoid `query_posts`, instead use WP_Query or hook into `pre_get_posts`. `query_posts` is **bad** practice, a performance hit/slowdown, and a source of many troubles. As a fulltime developer I wouldn't very strongly recommend against all use of that function, and many prominent WordPress developers and Wordpress Core devs would say and do say the same.

The reason your code doesn't work is because `query_posts` redoes the query, wasting the main query, and removing all the pagination query vars included.

Instead use the `pre_get_posts` filter to modify the homepage, e.g. to change the number of posts on the homepage:

```
function hwl_home_pagesize( $query ) {
    if ( is_home() && is_main_query()) {
        //Display only 1 post for the original blog archive
        $query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] = 1;
        return;
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'hwl_home_pagesize', 1);
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts

Comment: +1. You should probably add a `is_main_query()` conditional for the query modification. Also, based on context of the OP, I'd assume that your first suggestion - `WP_Query()` - is the better approach.

Comment: I did realize that in the Reading settings I had set it to show 14 per page. Still doesn't explain the page that only shows 13...

I'm new to WordPress: looking at the reference you gave it uses is_home as the example. How do I do that for a certain page instead (ie page id 2)?

Comment: It's bad practice to hard code page IDs etc, and you may not be able to use the page ID as the query hasn't been built and executed yet in that hook hence the 'pre' bit, you'll need to find another queryvar to match against, such as pagename